# listings package: embed text from a .txt file in a LaTeX document

Tags: listings

I'm using the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package to put text from a text file into a LaTeX document

```
\lstinputlisting{file.txt}
```

However, it isn't putting in special characters correctly, `%` is displaying fine which would have been the character I expected to display differently, but `£` is displaying as `c` with a `>` sign on top with the greater than part facing upwards.

Is there any way to get the characters to display correctly?

---

I can't login at the moment to update my question, but I have just been trying with a file created in notepad displaying special characters I used the phrase "£5.5K 70% 's a," and saved as a .txt encoded using either ANSI (produced the best results with only the £ symbol not looking right) and UTF 8 and Unicode both produce stranger results.

Dan

---

So far this is what I have using the tools package and Knitr

```
<<name, echo=FALSE, results='asis', eval=TRUE>>=   
    encoded_text_to_latex(as.character(SQL(paste("SELECT 'This is a test £5k 2.5m 70% !£$%^&*()_-`,#' AS `.`" , sep = "")), encoding = c("latin1","latin2","latin9","UTF-8","utf8"))

                      @
```

which gives me the following error

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) :
<text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: encoded text to latex(as.character(SQL(paste("SELECT ’This is a test Âc5k 2.5m 70%
!Âc$%ˆ&*() -‘,#’ AS ‘.‘" , sep = "")), encoding =
c("latin1","latin2","latin9","UTF-8","utf8"))
```

However I can get the following `. 1 This is a test Âc5k 2.5m 70` 
to appear by using

```
<<name, echo=FALSE, results='asis', eval=TRUE>>=   
    SQL(paste("SELECT 'This is a test £5k 2.5m 70% !£$%^&*()_-`,#' AS `.`" , sep = ""))
           @
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks guys, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Presumably your file is not in the encoding that listings expects. Please post a complete small document (and small text file) into your question so the problem is demonstrated. It probably works best to use a single byte encoding so `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` for example, and then save the files in that encoding (iso-8859-1).